# Java File Storege abstraction layer?

Tags: java, file

Does anybody uses some thirdparty library for files management, I mean save/delete/move files etc?

I am looking for something that gives me flexibility and independently of file system representation even if I'll decide to store files on ftp or something else it will be easy to achieve with this library.

I can write such abstraction layer or mini framework on my own, but I just don't wont to do that is already done.

Please advice me where to look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use Commons-VFS.  It provides a single API for numerous local and remote filesystems, and allows you to chain them as well.  For instance, you can file contained within a remote ZIP file hosted on an FTP server with a URL like

```
"zip://ftp://example.com/~user/mystuff.zip!/music/Devo/Whip It.mp3"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used Apaches [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) with great success. It was easy to for example switch from filesystem storage to FTP.